# Reusable CSS when different breakpoints are needed?

Tags: css

Im trying to make my CSS as modular and reusable as possible. Im using a media query to style a table differently for large and small screen widths. My issue is that different tables need the breakpoint at different widths.

Its not good for code maintenance to duplicate the same code and just change the breakpoint and selectors to change the breakpoint for a specific table, but do I have any other choices? Im sure SASS or LESS could solve this but im not using them, just plain old CSS.

Comment: Pure CSS can't (I think at least). But if you are not using LESS yet go ahead and start, it's wonderful.

Comment: One interesting method I've played with is using javascript to detect when a table is going to break the layout by exceeding the width of the element surrounding it. Once that happens, you could apply a class to the table that alters the styling.

Comment: How do you detect this? I guess you could see if the width of the table exceeded the width of its container?

Comment: No clear what you're asking for here.  What do you mean by "breakpoint"?

Comment: CSS breakpoint as defined by the media query.